# Why we can change input image size of darknet YOLO after training?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, yolo, darknet

Darknet yolo configuration files is something like this:

```
[net]
batch=64
subdivisions=8
height=416
width=416
channels=3
...
```

But we can change **height** and **width** without training the model and get a better result with higher image size (of course inference takes longer time). I'm a little confusing. What happens for weights when we change image size? For example if the first layer has N inputs and the second layer has M neurons then we should have (N*M + 1) weights, if the network is fully connected.
So the question is: how can we change N (width and height) without changing the weights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I'm also rather new to the topic, but I think that only Yolov1 uses fully connected layers. Have a look at the architecture of e.g. Yolov2. There are no FC layers, only convolution. This might be the answer?

Comment: Thanks for reply,
The fully connected layer was only for example, I don't mean that yolo has FC layers. If you change input size from 416 to 320, it propagates to all layers, but it is not necessary to change the .weight file after changing the input size for inference.

Comment: Yes I see your point. But if there are only convolution layer, aren't the weights the same, for any input size? What might change is the feature map size, so if you have a deviating input size for inference, then the output isn't 13x13 but something else. Imo removing all FC layers gives you an input-size independent network.

Comment: The point is that in convolutional layers only a single kernel (for example 3*3) will be trained and then this kernel can be applied to any input image, and because YOLO is fully convolutional network, we can pass image with any size after training.
Thanks for the key word: "input-size independent network"